# how to add/delete a textbox in the form on button click in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, onclick, event-handling

I have a form in which there is a field called "Poll Option". I want the textboxes should be added as well as deleted dynamically for "Poll Option" filed on button click.

I know the way of doing this using JQuery. But I don't know how to implement jquery in laravel. In which file should i dump the jquery code? Or is there any other way other than jQuery to achieve this?
My current js code is included in create.balde.php file. However it's not working. The javascript block is getting called but textbox is not appended.

The code is as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.pl').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#text').append('<input type="text" style="border:1px solid red;" value="Phone" class="form-control" size="15">');
    });
    $('.mi').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#text input').length > 1) {
            $('#text').children().last().remove();
        }
    });
});
</script>

{!!Form::open(['route'=>'admin.poll.store'])!!}

        {!!Form::label('title','Title:')!!}

        {!!Form::text('title','',[
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'placeholder'=>'Enter a title',
        'size'=>'15'

        ])!!}

        {!!Form::label('event_id','Event Id:')!!}

        {!!Form::text('event_id','',[
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'placeholder'=>'Enter event id',
        'size'=>'15'

        ])!!}

        {!!Form::label('text','Poll Option:')!!}

        {!!Form::text('text','',[
        'class'=>'form-control',
        'placeholder'=>'Enter poll option',
        'size'=>'15'

        ])!!}



        {!!Form::button('Add more options',['class'=>'pl'])!!}

        {!!Form::button('Delete options',['class'=>'mi'])!!}

        {!!Form::submit('Create')!!}





{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply write your `js` code in your views. Or, you can create js file inside `public/assets/js/your-file.js` and put your js code there.

And, in view you can call it like

```
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/your-file.js') }}"></script>
```

or, you may use `gulp` and handle your code there.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have added js code which is not working. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: have you added jquery.js

Comment: prevent form being submitted on clicking the button, by adding onsubmit false to the form tag. I mean just allow the form to be submitted after getting into the script.

Comment: tried with your solution.. still not working. I think the problem is because of the {{Form::text}} style of writing the form elements.

Comment: my problem is solved.. I didn't add the document.ready() function before writing the javascript function code. After adding that, the problem got solved. :